# MySQL won't allow login with correct user information

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I am having a bizarre problem. I have installed MySQL with homebrew on OSX 10.8.5 and when I try to login it with mysql -uroot -p it doesn't even prompt for a password, it just says Starting MySQL SUCCESS!, but will not login to the MySQL console. I ran the secure_installation and set a password for root which appeared to work fine. I have tried completely uninstalling it multiple times with brew uninstall and brew cleanup but nothing has fixed it. I have scoured the internets but have found nothing. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the log file from /usr/local/var/mysql:

```
2013-10-25 15:22:12 70321 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2013-10-25 15:22:12 70321 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2013-10-25 15:22:12 70321 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-10-25 15:22:12 70321 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.13'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
131025 15:22:15 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
131025 15:22:20 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
131025 15:23:30 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
131025 15:30:57 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
131025 15:31:01 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
131028 08:49:14 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
131028 08:49:22 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

Comment: have you got a log file?

Comment: I added the log file and have now seen that any mysql command results in Starting MySQL SUCCESS! Even mysql --help won't work.